# External file for strings, as opposed to hardcoding them

Tags: java, eclipse, file, hard-coding

I have experience developing some Android apps, which handily have XML string files where you can store strings. The last time I developed a desktop Java app I hard-coded the strings (for example button titles, labels etc...). I have since learned this is bad practice, and I should store strings in a file.

I am not sure how to go about doing this.

- I am currently developing in Eclipse. Should I just stick a text file in my project folder?
- Is this standard?
- How do you locate the file in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should use `.properties` files and access them using [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Answer (score 9):

Eclipse has a built-in refactoring that you may find useful.

```
Source->Externalise Strings
```

This creates a properties file with the strings stored as key/value pairs.

Behind the scenes it is using `ResourceBundle`

Answer (score 3):

I think if you do this it will not be specific to any IDE:  See [Load resources via a resources file](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0135.html) for an overview.  The 1st URL states this about where this class looks for the properties files.

See the [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)   class.

The `ResourceBundle` will look first for classes and if not found, it will look for properties files. We don't have to specify file names, the `ResourceBundle` will construct the file name using the same mechanism used for classes. The file must have the extension `.properties`.

The `ResourceBundle` try to load the properties file from the current class-path.

If the properties are stored in sub-directory, use `.` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for `ResourceBundle`.  The API provides a way to fetch strings for locale specific resources.